# Сползает background

Tags: html, css

Скажите почему картинка сползает? У меня все было 1170, контейнер так же. А этот блок надо выставить на всю ширину, ставлю 100% — и она начинает сползать, а текст остается на месте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 680px;
    background: url(../img/background2.png) no-repeat;  
   
}
```

```
.block2 {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
height: 680px;
background: url(../img/background2.png) no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: код было бы неплохо посмотреть

Comment: если картинка - бекграунд, значит этот блок у вас вне контейнера 1170px. И послушайте @Назара Калитюка, покажите код, шаманы с бубнами все ушли на север)

Comment: .block2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 680px;
    background: url(../img/background2.png) no-repeat;  
   
}

Answer (score 1):

Напишите в CSS блока, в котором фоновая картинка:

```
background-size:cover
```

Таким образом картинка будет растягиваться на всю ширину.

[Подробнее о background-size](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 - выровнять сам блок и задать адаптивность картинке внутри:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Вариант 2 - картинка-фон:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
   
</div>
```